# Using $do_not_duplicate several times in Wordpress to avoid duplicate posts

Tags: wordpress

I wonder if you can help with what I hope is an easy-to-solve Wordpress problem?

I've created a magazine-style theme at http://www.totalbackpacker.co.uk, which has three 'featured' stories at the top of the page, followed by most the most recent posts below.

Using the `$do_not_duplicate` method (http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops_in_Action), I've been able to omit the post that is displayed as the main featured story in the list of most recent posts ... but I run into difficulties when trying to omit the second and third featured stories, presumably because `$do_not_duplicate` is only intended to be used once.

I'm displaying the main featured story using:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=editors-picks-main&posts_per_page=1'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
```

So it's basically pulling the most recent post from the `editors-picks-main` category.

The 'second' featured story (the most recent post from the `editors-picks-sub-1` category) is displayed using:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=editors-picks-sub-1&posts_per_page=1'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

And the 'third' featured story (the most recent post from the `editors-picks-sub-2` category) using:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=editors-picks-sub-2&posts_per_page=1'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

For the most recent posts section (note: the posts are spread over two columns, so this code is repeated) I'm using:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=blog&posts_per_page=4'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php if ($count == 1) : ?>
<h5 class="smaller"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
<p class="editorspickssml"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php elseif ($count == 2) : ?>
Second post here
<?php elseif ($count == 3) : ?>
Third post here
<?php elseif ($count == 4) : ?>
Fourth post here
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I may be able to get this to work? I know I need to add something similar to `$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>` to the code code for `editors-picks-sub-1` and `editors-picks-sub-2` ... I'm just not sure what!

I'd be really grateful for any tips!

Thanks in advance for your help,

Martin

Comment: I wondered whether it would work if I added `$do_not_duplicate2 = $post->ID; ?` to the `editors-picks-sub-1` section and `$do_not_duplicate3 = $post->ID; ?` to the `editors-picks-sub-2` section, then used `if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate || $do_not_duplicate2 || $do_not_duplicate3 ) continue; ?>` for the most recent posts ... but it doesn't seem to. Am I on the right track though? Thanks!

Comment: Ahh, yes I was on the right track! I'm just about to post the answer ...

Comment: OK, can't post answer yet ... but start by using `$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;` in the first loop of post(s) you don't want to duplicate.

Then use `$do_not_duplicate2 = $post->ID;`, `$do_not_duplicate3 = $post->ID;`, `$do_not_duplicate4 = $post->ID;` etc for any further loop(s) of post(s) you don't want to duplicate.

For the loop(s) where you want to avoid including duplicated posts, simply use:

`if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate || $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate2 || $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate3 || $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate4 ) continue; update_post_caches($posts);`

Answer (score 0):

Collect the ID's of the first three 'featured posts' in a variable.

Create an array, before your loops to hold the ID's of the posts to exclude:

```
$exclude = new Array();
```

In you first, second and third loop add the ID of the post to the array:

```
array_push($exclude,$post->ID);
```

Then exclude those ID's from your recent posts query.

```
query_posts('category_name=blog&posts_per_page=4&post__not_in='.$exclude);
```

Note: I'm not sure you should be using query posts like that, its quite a lot of query editing going on. Also if you want pagination to work you need to include the paged variable.